# For Loop 'i' Logic

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, cocos2d-iphone

Right now I have this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < level.contentSize.width/level.tileSize.width; i ++){
    tile = [levelLayer tileAt:ccp(i,17)];
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.boundingBox, tile.boundingBox)) {
        NSLog(@"hit");
    }
}
```

What I need to have is two variables (right now I have one- `i`) so that I can check all tiles in all x and y values. So the `tile = [levelLayer tileAt:ccp(i,j)];` <---would look like that.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear... what do you want to do with your variable? Please make the effort to paraphrase your question in more adequate and proper English because as it's standing, it's almost completely incomprehensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using inner for-loop with another loop variable j iterating through all possible values. Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < level.contentSize.width/level.tileSize.width; i ++)
    for (int j = 0; j < level.contentSize.height/level.tileSize.height; j ++){

        tile = [levelLayer tileAt:ccp(i,j)];
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.boundingBox, tile.boundingBox)) {
            NSLog(@"hit");
        }
}
```

Comment: This worked great! Thank you so much. It drops in FPS but I'm guess ion if I take out the NSLog that won't happen.

Comment: if performance drops and your level size is much bigger then tile size (so number of loop iterations becomes really large) you probably should think about optimizing your loop somehow (e.g. break from it if you need only one intersection detected, or narrow the range of possible values of i and j). As you use cocos2d, may be you can use collision detection functions provided by physic engines like box2d?

Comment: No it was just that it would log every time the two rects intersected, almost 5-9 times a second just for one block... Took it out and now it back to 60.

Answer (score 1):

**Use separate `for` loops.**

A `for` loop iterates over some range of values. If you want to iterate over two separate ranges, using two for loops is a good idea because it clearly communicates what you're doing. If the body of the loop is more than a line or two, you might want to break it out into its own function or method, or even use a block that you define just before the loops. That way, you can be sure that both loops perform exactly the same task and it's just the range of values that's different.

There are other possible solutions for dealing with several ranges of indices. You could, for example, add both ranges to a NSMutableIndexSet and then iterate over all the indices using `-enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:`.

But seriously, just use two `for` loops.

Comment: But how do I access the variables for the different loops?

Comment: @stenger96 Sorry, I understood you to mean that you wanted to loop over the two ranges sequentially, not together. Nested `for` loops as suggested by Vladimir is the right answer is the right way to search two ranges together.